# Using Appium + Selenium with Android Studio

Tags: android, selenium, android-studio, ui-automation, appium

We are migrating to Android Studio and are having issues migrating the Test Module from Eclipse to Android Studio.

The test module uses some cucumber-java and selenium-server jars which we use to communicate with an appium server. The test project cannot compile with the selenium jars. Following is the stack trace.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad utf-8 byte 9e at offset 00000002
        at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:374)
        at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:262)
        at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:294)
        at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
        at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
        at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:279)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad utf-8 byte 9e at offset 00000002
        at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.throwBadUtf8(CstString.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.utf8BytesToString(CstString.java:143)
        at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.<init>(CstString.java:200)
        at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:371)
        ... 22 more
    ...while parsing cst 03be at offset 000025db
    ...while parsing cst 0007 at offset 0000001e
    ...while parsing org/apache/xalan/res/XSLTErrorResources_ru.class

    1 error; aborting
```

I could resolve the issue using xalan-2.7.2 in the project, but then it fails with xerces jar with the same error.

The project structure is

```
├── app
 |   ├── build.gradle
 │   └── src
 │   └── main
 │      ├── java
 │      │   └── com
 │      │   └── ...
 │      ├── res
 │      | └── ...
 │      └── AndroidManifest.xml
    └── androidTest
        └──java
               └── main
                       └── feature files and step definitions etc 
 └── build.gradle
```

I also tried excluding the dependencies in gradle as follows:

```
  androidTestCompile('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.43.1') {
        exclude module: 'xalan'
        exclude module: 'xerces'

    }
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.1.5',
            'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.1.5',
            'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.0',
            'info.cukes:gherkin:2.12.2',
            'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5',
            'io.appium:java-client:1.0.1',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3',
            'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1',
            'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
```

but this also does not solve the issue.

Is there a way to make make the android studio compile test project with selenium jars?